# West Virginia or New Jersey state income taxes

Tags: united-states, taxes, state-income-tax, form-1099-misc

I live in Texas.  I receive oil and gas royalties income from my properties in West Virginia. I have the 1099-MISC. The company that sent me the 1099 MISC is located in New Jersey.  What state do I pay state income tax to?  West Virginia or New Jersey or both?